# Where can I find Video for Windows (VFW)

Tags: c++, windows, video, media, vfw

I am working on a project that uses VFW. I have done Google searches for it, but not exactly sure what I am looking for. I have a few questions about it. Is it a dll? If so, where could I find it? Is it still supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an almost obsolete technology, originally for Windows 3.1! See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_for_Windows) article for a start, and then proceed to [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).